# Find exact and partial matches in the tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables products and users. I need to find exact and partial matches in these tables.

For example, there is a user with the username cat, and there is a product with the name cat. And there are products with the names of a good cat, red cat.

I want to get exact matches and partial matches. That is, get a user and three products.

I tried to do so, but the query returns an empty body.

```
SELECT P.*, U.*
    FROM PRODUCTS AS P
        LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON (U.USER_ID = P.STORE_ID)
            WHERE 
                P.PRODUCT_NAME = 'cat' OR P.PRODUCT_NAME LIKE ('%cat%')
                AND U.USERNAME = 'cat' OR U.USERNAME LIKE ('%cat%')
                    GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID, U.USER_ID
```

How do I get a user and products for the word cat? Partial and exact matches.

Comment: Are you sure about: `ON (U.USER_ID = P.STORE_ID)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `OR` instead of `AND`, also `'cat'` is `LIKE '%cat%` so you do not need to check with `=` also

```
SELECT P.*, U.*
    FROM PRODUCTS AS P
        LEFT JOIN USERS AS U ON (U.USER_ID = P.STORE_ID)
            WHERE P.PRODUCT_NAME LIKE ('%cat%')
               OR U.USERNAME LIKE ('%cat%')
                    GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID, U.USER_ID
```